# Passing variables in event listener not working

Tags: javascript

I have a simple event listener and I am trying to pass variables to a function but it's not working... this is what I have:

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('cursor').addEventListener("mousedown", mousePos, false);
}

function mousePos(e) {
    var x = e.clientX;
    var y = e.clientY;
    document.getElementById('cursor').addEventListener("mousemove", function () {
        mousemoveCalc(x, y);
    }, false);
}

function mousemoveCalc(e, x, y) {
    console.log(e);
    console.log(x); //undefined
    console.log(y); //undefined
}
```

I'm getting undefined for `x` and `y` but I do not know how to solve it =/ They are not undefined however in mousePos =/

How do i fix this ?

Comment: Why do you set a new mousemove listener on every mousedown?!

Comment: There is only one mouse down ? Its a click and drag so it needs to mouse down first.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/

looks like all you need to do is pass the event, then do e.pageX and e.pageY...

Comment: No i need the starting x and y for click down to compare it when i move the mouse to calculate how far the mouse moved.

Comment: Works for me. Can you make a JSFiddle that shows the issue?

Comment: @Pumbaa80 the problem seems to lie with including `(e,x,y)` for arguements removing the `e` seems to allow x and y to be set.. but then i lose e.

Comment: Use `addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
        mousemoveCalc(e, x, y);`

Comment: That kind of worked but x and y some times gets undefined as i move the mouse, but only once ever so often, very odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this fiddle to see if this is close to what you are looking for.
http://jsfiddle.net/cF6fE/2/

```
  var posx = 0;
    var posy = 0;
    window.onload = function() {

        document.getElementById('cursor').addEventListener("mousedown", mousePos, false);
    }

    function mousePos(e) {
        posx = e.clientX;
        posy = e.clientY;
        document.getElementById('cursor').addEventListener("mousemove", mousemoveCalc);
    }

    function mousemoveCalc(e) {
        console.log(e);
      var x = e.clientX;
        var y = e.clientY;
    var xOffset  = posx-x;
    var yOffset  = posy-y;
        console.log(x); 
        console.log(y); 
     console.log(xOffset); 
        console.log(yOffset); 
    }
```

#### Update:- with [Function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

http://jsfiddle.net/uGuHk/

```
function mousePos(e) {
        var posx = e.clientX;
        var posy = e.clientY;
        document.getElementById('cursor').addEventListener("mousemove", mousemoveCalc.bind(this, posx,posy));
    }

    function mousemoveCalc(xax,yax,e) {

        console.log(e);
      var x = e.clientX;
        var y = e.clientY;
    var xOffset  = xax-x;
    var yOffset  = yax-y;
        console.log(x); //undefined
        console.log(y); //undefined
     console.log(xOffset); //undefined
        console.log(yOffset); //undefined
    }
```

#### Update2:- With Closure

http://jsfiddle.net/FG6uW/

```
function mousePos(e) {
        var posx = e.clientX;
        var posy = e.clientY;
        document.getElementById('cursor').addEventListener("mousemove", function() {
            (function(x, y) {
                mousemoveCalc(x, y)
            })(posx, posy)
        });
    }

    function mousemoveCalc(xax, yax) {

        var x = event.clientX;
        var y = event.clientY;
        var xOffset = xax - x;
        var yOffset = yax - y;
        console.log(xax);
        console.log(yax);

        document.getElementById('cursor').innerText = xax + '-' + yax + '|' + xOffset + '-' + yOffset;
        console.log(xOffset);
        console.log(yOffset);
    }
```

Comment: Alternatively, for older browsers that doesn't have `bind` you can simply use a closure.